# Languages supporting manual memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, programming-languages

In C one can have a tight control over his memory, allocate & deallocate at well and access specific memory addresses etc..., I was wondering -out of curiosity-, what other programming languages that allows me to do this? Have this strict control over my memory? Other than -obviously- C++.

Comment: C++  comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah but I consider it a daughter of C so same thing, my bad gonna edit the question.

Comment: Assembler comes to mind. But not all systems will allow you to access a specific address (or the hardware), on many it is a virtual address.

Comment: Most [system programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming_language) allow explicit memory allocation.  (Scroll down for a short list.)

Comment: Why do you wonder? Is it just plain curiosity (which is okay, but please state it)? Or is there some other problem you need to solve and think you need explicit memory management to do it?

Comment: FORTH comes to mind.

Comment: Delphi, Pascal...

Comment: C# to mention beside C++.

Comment: Actually we could rephrase the question somewhat differently, which system programming language doesn't allow manual memory management?